# What alternatives there are for Object.create (when setting state to React component)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a helper function which is supposed to set state for parent and therefore trigger onUpdate to child component:

```
validateInput: function (inputValue, inputName, inputRules, setFormState, formFields) {
    let hasError = false;
    let errorText = false;
    if (!inputValue && inputRules.required) {
        hasError = true;
        errorText = 'This field is required.';
    }
    else {
        hasError = false;
        errorText = false;
    };
    state = { fields: Object.create(formFields) };
    state.fields[inputName].hasError = hasError;
    state.fields[inputName].errorText = errorText;

    return setFormState(state);
}
```

This gives me the desired effect and the child component updates. But if I log the state in the parent component, I get empty object. The values are found under *proto* when I log, and I don't actually fully understand the whole object prototype of JavaScript.

If I modify the code so, that the state variable is following

```
state = { fields: formFields };
```

the situation turns around. I get the right state in parent component, but child component update is not triggered.

What alternatives I have for using Object.create()? Why is this happening?

I'd also like to add, that I know the title of this question is silly, this just really gets me lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly sure what `setFormState` or `formFields` look like, but you could almost certainly avoid using prototypes here.

For example, you could merge all the properties with `Object.assign`:

```
let form = { hasError, errorText };
let fields = Object.assign({}, formFields, form);
let state = { fields };
return setFormState(state);
```

This will create a new `fields` object that has all of the properties from both `formFields` and `form`.

Comment: This fixed it. I am quite sure that I was doing something wrong when using an object reference to the original state but still no clue of the exact reasoning behind the setState()/update children behaviour.

Comment: There is still some confusion remaining over the Object.assign behaviour. Can you take a look of this: http://pastebin.com/ifcA7w4J? I am sending the formFields object to this function, and depending how I use Object.assign it modifies the original object in the caller function.

Comment: The first one creates a shallow copy of `formFields` on L4, which means the nested objects are still references and you mutate them on L5-6. The second one replaces the nested object at `inputName` with the new `field` object.

Comment: And the other nested objects are still references, but since I don't manipulate them in this function the original formFields in the caller function stays untouched. I think I got it now.